# Clear specific controller session in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

In my project I'm using session to maintain some complex type data. I want to clear that session if that **specified controller has not been hit for a specified amount of time** , need to clear that specific session only that have been used in that controller not all the entire user session .

Let say,

**BusinessController** has some ActionMethods like **Test1, Test2** .

The ActionMethod Test1 has some Session like **Session["MyData"], Session["ListOfBusiness"]** . 
The ActionMethod Test2 has some Session like **Session["MyDataNew"], Session["ListOfBusiness"]** .

I need to **clear the session Session["MyData"], Session["ListOfBusiness"]** only if **BusinessController has not been hit for some time**.

Thanks,

Guna

Answer (score 0):

You can user ActionFilterAttribute. This will be called for every action so you can check in it whether controller has been hit or not.And for checking you can create a session in whcih you can store time when that controller hits or you can store time in database.

Whenever your BusinessController gets hit store time in session or database and when ActionFilterAttribute is execites get the time when BusinessController was las hit. I hope i have explained clearly.

Comment: @Ahmad thanks for your reply,
If we set condition at ActionFilterAttribute it will be execute for the each and every request to check whether this is BusinessController  or not. Is it the correct way?.

Comment: Can we do this process at BusinessController Dispose method by calling the thread to check the last access time and remove the session?

Comment: Dispose of BussinessController will only be called when it will finish executing so this will not make sense.